# Fix time string

Tags: php, regex

This should be very easy, but I am not getting it.  I wish to receive hours:minutes, and return hours:minutes:seconds in 00:00:00 format.  The following falls way short.  Recommendations on the best way to do this?  Thank you

```
<?php
    function fixTime($t)
    {
        $a = explode(':', trim($t));
        return ((count($a)==2) && ($h=$a[0]) && ($m=$a[1]) && ($h>=0) && ($m>=0) && ($h<=23) && ($m<=59))?$h.':'.$m.':00':'00:00:00';
    }

    echo(fixTime('23:33').'<br />');
    echo(fixTime('05:00').'<br />');
    echo(fixTime('5:00').'<br />');
?>
```

Comment: $SomeKittens.  $m=$a[1] is false, so returns 00:00:00 regardless of whether there are any hours. Same but reverse for $h=$a[0]

Comment: @PeeHaa.  Yes, I can add :00, but wanted to have some sort of validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function will help you out here:

```
function fixTime($t) {
    return date('H:i:s', strtotime($t));
}

echo fixTime('23:33'); // 23:33:00
echo fixTime('05:00'); // 05:00:00
echo fixTime('5:00'); // 05:00:00
```

Also, see the [date](http://php.net/date) function for a list of formatting options available.

To validate such simple input, a regular expression might be helpful:

```
function fixTime($t) {
    if (!preg_match('/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/', $t)) {
        return false;
    }
    return date('H:i:s', strtotime($t));
}

echo fixTime('23:33'); // 23:33:00
echo fixTime('33:33'); // false

if (fixTime('33:33') === false) {
    // invalid date supplied
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on advantages between the two solutions?

Comment: Well, the regular expression validating the input is a trivial amount of extra processing, so I would be inclined to go ahead and use the second method with the validation unless you can be confident that your input will always be valid

Comment: @PeeHaa Good catch, edited the regex for posterity. I hadn't seen the comment about returning `00:00:00` for invalid times, if that's the desired behaviour then the regex is indeed unnecessary.