# How to convert number and decimal into HH:MM

Tags: php

I have a variable `$route->flighttime` which echoes numbers in the following format...

```
0.5
1.2
1.45
```

How do I convert it to display `HH:MM` using `echo`?

Note: `0.5` is treated by the CMS as 50 minutes for some reason.

Comment: But what is the relationship, should we assume currently it's   H.MM ?

Comment: actually there was a post similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940072/fix-time-string

Comment: The question is not clear. All the answers assume (as I did, too) that 0.5 is half an hour, but from your comments, it seems to be 50 minutes. You can use Jon's answer, in this case, but multiply by 100 instead of 60 on the second line of code

Comment: 100 works, but I found that 101 is more precise. I'm not sure if it's a good solution?

Comment: Can you give an example where 101 is more precise than 100?

Comment: 100 displays something like `02:39` on `2.40` whereas 101 calculates it as `02:40`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on OPs comments about the format of his initial time (where .5 is actually 50 minutes), a solution without any math

```
$time = floatval($route->flighttime);
echo number_format($time,2,':',null);
```

Comment: +1, nice thinking, although it will take something more to pad the hours to two digits if needed. Small issue: `number_format` will error out if called with exactly three parameters (:rolleyes: PHP); I edited to add the fourth one.

Comment: Thanks Jon.... I hadn't actually tested, but it simply seemed a more logical solution

Comment: Thank you, I've noticed a warning, but you quickly replied with a solution, before I had time to look it up in the documentation :P How would I pad it to two digits? Changing the value in `number_format` only changes the digits after the colon.

Comment: @zzwyb89: Go to the PHP website and search for "pad". `str_pad` won't be hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

#### If the input is a floating point value of hours

First convert the floating point value to hours/minutes:

```
$hours = floor($route->flighttime);
$minutes = ($route->flighttime - $hours) * 60;
```

#### If the input is a hours/minutes pair tortured to fit into a float

You can either multiply by 100 instead of 60, or use this technique which might be more accurate:

```
list($hours, $minutes) = explode('.', sprintf('%.2F', $route->flighttime));
```

#### In any case

Then use `printf` (or some similar function such as `sprintf`) to format it properly:

```
printf("%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes);
```

Comment: It's doing what's intended in regards to the format, but for some reason, it's showing for example 00:30 for 0.5. I can only assume that PHP is logically treating 0.5 as a half, is that right? If so, how can I change it so it displays 00:50? Would I have to change the values in the database or is there a way to format this?

Comment: Does `0.5` mean five minutes or half an hour? If it means fifty minutes (wtf?!?) then how do you represent five minutes?

Comment: `0.5` means 50 minutes. 5 minutes is merely represented by `0.05`, it's set by a CMS :| I figured out that changing the number from 60 to 101 beside `$minutes` makes it work, but it's probably an awful solution.

Comment: @zzwyb89: What's really awful is the format you are given. But why 101?

Comment: 100 displays something like `02:39` on `2.40` whereas `101` calculates it as `02:40`

Comment: @zzwyb89: 101 is just horrible. Take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming 0.5 means half of an hour. Use `gmdate` with format `G:i` and your time in seconds:

```
echo gmdate('G:i', round($x * 3600));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gmstrftime("%H:%M", $t * 60 * 60);
```

... where $t is float in hours. Notice use of gmstrftime instead of strftime, becouse you do not want to play with timezones.

Answer (score 0):

If the current format is hour and minutes separated by a dot, you could use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('G.i', '9.15');
echo $time->format('H:i');
```

However, in this format, `5` in the minutes section would be 5 minutes, not 50 minutes.